# Linq To Sql table association on DateTime properties using British database login

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have two tables Parent and Child. Both tables have a primary key "MyDate" declared as DateTime in Sql Server. Both tables have a record where MyDate is set to "2011-12-01 00:00:00.000", i.e., 1st December 2011.

In my Linq to SQL dbml (.Net 3.5) I have an automatically created association between the two tables, on the MyDate property. The DataContext uses a login to the database that has its Default language set to "British English" in SQL Server (2008). When I run the Linq query:

```
var query
  from parent in myDataContext.PARENTs
  select parent
```

I get back Parent records but not the linked Child records.

In SQL Profiler I have this trace:

```
-- network protocol: TCP/IP
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language British
set dateformat dmy
set datefirst 1
set transaction isolation level read committed
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[MyDate] FROM [dbo].[CHILD] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[MYDATE] = @p0)','@p0 datetime',@p0='2011-12-01 00:00:00'
```

This returns 0 records; I have checked it by running it directly in a query window, using the same (British) login. If I comment out the "set dateformat dmy" I still get 0 records. If I run it using a login that is not British, I get a record back. If I use '01-12-2011 00:00:00' as the date (e.g., UK date format) and the British login, I get a record back.

It seems to me that Linq is not using the correct date format when it creates the date string to use in its query. As it is using "set dateformat dmy", why is it not using that format in the date string it generates?

Is there a relatively simple way to fix this? Thanks.

Edit: in my model the MyDate property on both Parent and Child has a Server Data Type of "DateTime NOT NULL", and a Type of "DateTime (System.DateTime)".

Comment: #In your LINQ model, is it `DateTime`? or some kind of string? Likewise, in the C# generated code. Basically, it should **never** be passing a date as a string. If you are doign that, you've done something wrong. It should always be a typed parameter, thereby culture is irrelevent. I suspect the value of `@p0` you are seeing is merely a *representation*, and that the value sent is actually a binary float that is the same date in every culture.

Comment: Yes it is DateTime in my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try eager loading

[LINQ to SQL: Lazy and Eager Loading Hiccups](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/12/02/linq-to-sql-lazy-and-eager-loading-hiccups/)

```
var query = (from parent in MyDataContext.Parents select parent)
                .Including(childs => parent.Childs);
```

or

try out

```
from parent in Parents select new
     {parent.Name, parent.Whatever,
     Childs =
         parent.Childs.where(c=>c.Date== parent.Date) };
```

Comment: I don't have Including available; according to your link it was killed by Microsoft ;-(

Comment: I would like to avoid your second suggestion, because it seems I would have to name all the columns on my Parent table (there are a lot!). Thanks anyway.